# laravel issue when upload images to s3 and store the paths in database

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I am new the this PHP things
and I wanna create a article model which has  title and some images

what  I can do is `save the title to my database`
but not the uploaded images , `even more  , I don't know how to upload multiple images with php or should I call laravel ?`

one single image is fine with me and I know the callback will tell me the image address  but what indeed should I do to store them in database and relate them in the specific article model ?

many many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok let me address this issue, your uploaded image should be renamed using timestamp reason is to avoid name collision. Look at this for example
    $filename_path = md5(time().uniqid()).".jpg"; 
This ensures that you will always have unique name for the file.
Once you rename the file and move to s3 then you save $filename_path into a table.

During retrieval you get the name and search your s3 bucket for the image.

Hope this helps

Comment: when uploaded to s3, the upload function should give me a callback which is JSON or JSON like data format which contains the file name ? and I save that name to my table ? should I have a unique folder for each uploader to manage the uploaded files ?

Comment: Not really a callback per se. You have the id of the last inserted record. It is what you should use to id the image to the record of the uploaded record. Save it in the table. No point creating folders everywhere. The Id should uniquely identify the image.